# Filter out List (which is null) in .SelectMany() EFCore-Db Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Imagine following scenario:

I have a table `StringFeature` with `stringFeatures` in it. Other tables like `AssortmentArticle` or `Article` reference this feature in a n-n relation. When I'm trying to delete this feature, i need to check if it's still in a relation with another Table (different Tables may point to the same Feature)

Here a codesnippet as a example for the following question)

```cs
public static async Task TryRemoveItemFromList<T>(AssortmentContext context, List<T> listToRemoveFrom, T itemToRemove, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (itemToRemove is not null)
    {
        //Todo check for all relations
        var needsToBeRemoved = true;
        if (itemToRemove is Feature<string> stringFeatureToRemove)
        {
            needsToBeRemoved = (
                await context.AssortmentArticles
                .SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).FirstAsync(sf => sf.Id == stringFeatureToRemove.Id, cancellationToken) is null &&
                await context.AssortmentArticleHasFeatureGroups
                .SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).FirstAsync(sf => sf.Id == stringFeatureToRemove.Id, cancellationToken) is null &&
                await context.Articles
                .SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).FirstAsync(sf => sf.Id == stringFeatureToRemove.Id, cancellationToken) is null &&
                await context.ValidCombinations
                .SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).FirstAsync(sf => sf.Id == stringFeatureToRemove.Id, cancellationToken) is null &&
                await context.Coatings
                .SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).FirstAsync(sf => sf.Id == stringFeatureToRemove.Id, cancellationToken) is null
                );
       }

       listToRemoveFrom.Remove(itemToRemove);

       if (needsToBeRemoved)
       {
            try
            {
                context.Remove(itemToRemove);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new DbUpdateException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

Here i check for all posible Tables which may include this feature. After the check i try to remove that feature (should always work after check, try-catch is just a safety-fallback.

However, the `x.StringFeatures` List (List of StringFeatures) is nullable, which may break the `SelectMany`. When I try to filter out the the possible null `StringFeatures with`

```cs
...
.Where(x => x.Stringfeatures != null)
...
```

I get an error saying that `The LINGQ Expression ... could not be translated`.

I understand the error, however fixing it is my problem. I've tried changing to

```cs
...
.SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures ?? Enumerable.Empty<List<Feature<string>>>())
...
```

however, that didn't work either.

### TL;DR

How does one filter out a null-List in a LINQ query?

Comment: You can use `AnyAsync` instead of `FirstAsync(..) is null`. And `FirstAsync` will throw if no matching row is present. And `SelectMany` won't throw for null values as it will converted into SQL

Comment: Collection navigation properties should never be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this query in one database roundtrip:

```cs
var query = 
    from item in context.Set<T>()
    where item.Id == stringFeatureToRemove.Id
    where !context.AssortmentArticles.SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).Any(sf => sf.Id == item.Id)
    where !context.AssortmentArticleHasFeatureGroups.SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).Any(sf => sf.Id == item.Id)
    where !context.Articles.SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).Any(sf => sf.Id == item.Id)
    where !context.ValidCombinations.SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).Any(sf => sf.Id == item.Id)
    where !context.Coatings.SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).Any(sf => sf.Id == item.Id)
    select item;

needsToBeRemoved = await query.AnyAsync();
```

Or another approach using `LEFT JOIN`, which can be faster:

```cs
var query = 
    from item in context.Set<T>()
    where item.Id == stringFeatureToRemove.Id
    from t1 in context.AssortmentArticles.SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).Where(sf => sf.Id == item.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where t1 == null
    from t2 in context.AssortmentArticleHasFeatureGroups.SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).Where(f => sf.Id == item.Id).DefaultIfEmpty() 
    where t2 == null
    from t3 in context.Articles.SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).Where(sf => sf.Id == item.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where t3 == null
    from t4 in context.ValidCombinations.SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).Where(sf => sf.Id == item.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where t4 == null
    from t5 in context.Coatings.SelectMany(x => x.StringFeatures).Where(sf => sf.Id == item.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where t5 == null
    select item;

needsToBeRemoved = await query.AnyAsync();
```

Comment: Does it make sense to do everything in one roundtrip? I mean, if any of the queries are true, the rest wont even query because the expression is already evaluated as "false" isn't it?

Comment: In worse case you will execute 5 queries. Here we have only one. Roundtrip to database is expensive operation.

Comment: So you think 1 Database query joint will be faster than (possibly up to) 5 seperate ones? I'd have to test, that, but thanks!

Comment: Even better you can delete this item by `await query.ExecuteDeleteAsync()` with EF Core 7